# php function: number_format()

Tags: php

```
$result = number_format($x, 2, '.', ','); //Will do the following correctly
115255 = 115,225.00
115255.4 = 115,225.40
115255.40 = 115,225.40
115255.455 = 115,255.46
```

But I need when the user enters more than 2 digits after the decimal, not to cut them into 2 decimals only and to use it as it is...

```
115255.455 = 115,255.455
115255.4557 = 115,255.4557
```

Can I do something like that?

```
if($x == number_format($x, 3)) //I will do it in while loop later, lets test 3 now
    $result = number_format($x, 3, '.', ',');
else $result = number_format($x, 2, '.', ',');
```

The previous if condition never works, else only works

Comment: Hm, why you just dont separate the number and format only the integer, and then append the fraction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One not traditional way to do this:

```
$parts = explode(".", $x);
$integerPart = number_format($parts[0], 0, '', ',');
$result = $integerPart.".".$parts[1];
```

Comment: yup, if it's possible :)

Comment: can I explode it to use it like $parts[0]